# Create a chart in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I'm having some trouble creating charts in Excel with C#. I've managed to get a chart of any kind working with the following code:

```
            Excel.Range chartRange; 

            Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
            Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

            chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "Y2");
            chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
            chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```

Unfortunately, I'm not really sure what to do next. Here is what I want to do:

1) There are supposed to be several rows of data, but they are not next to each other (E.g. A2:Y2; A4:Y4; A6:Y6;). How do I add each of these to the chart?

2) A1:Y1 has all of the values for my legend, how would I add this in to the legend?

3) How can I change it so that each chart is created on a new tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured out answer to question 1:

```
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B137:Y137, B139:Y139, B141:Y141", Missing.Value);
```

Now figured out answer to question 3:

```
chartPage.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet, "Chart1");
```

And finally the answer to Question 2 was to simply add the row names as part of the selection, so as #2 but A instead of B.

Comment: How did you add the row names to the selection?: "And finally the answer to Question 2 was to simply add the row names as part of the selection, so as #2 but A instead of B."